# Shopify: calling swatch.liquid 'colors' on collection.liquid and product-loop.liquid

Tags: shopify

I have not been able to find a fix for my issue. I want to show a simple "More Colors" option beneath the product prices.

[Screenshot of Product example](http://www.uploady.com/#!/download/V31IGO~SNnu/VGgGalA_VWrDUrwb)

I have been testing code such as:

```
  {% if product.variants 'color' > 1 %}  
  Has more than one variant.
  {% else %}Only one variant.
  {% endif %}
```

But haven't had any luck. Everything either calls "Has more..." or "Only one..." regarless of the swatch count.

I am editing `product-loop.liquid` which is being called from `collections.liquid`

It has only outputed "Only one variant" or "Has more than one variant" for every product regardless of swatch/color count.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

This statement is nonsense:

```
{% if product.variants 'color' > 1 %}
```

Instead, you want to check the options set for your variants, and if you detect an option set to color, and you have more than one variant, then clearly, you are in more than one color territory.

```
{% assign has_more_colors = false %}
{% for option in product.options %}
    {% if option contains 'color' and product.variants.length > 1 %}
       {% assign has_more_colors = true %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

So now you can do whatever it is you need to do... since you now know you a) have an option called colors, and b) more than one variant, hence more than one color...

Comment: I dropped this into `product-loop` and not sure why it doesn't output anything. This seems like it would work, but do I need to create a variable has_more_colors or is that a part of liquid markup? I'm new to this..  thx

Comment: Yes. You would simply check your new shiny variable.

    {% if has_more_colors %}
        <p> MORE COLORS</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Living large in a monochrome world</p>
    {% endif %}

Comment: Still haven't gotten it to fire correctly on products with more than one color. Perhaps it's because of having only 1 size? I.e - wallets: 1 size, and multiple colors.

Comment: also here is a gist of our `swatch.liquid` markup (if it helps): [Gist](https://gist.github.com/s0rfila/ae0c448535c3053b93cb#file-gistfile1-txt)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet was posted to the Shopify boards. It solved this issue:

```
{% assign option_title = "Color" %}
{% assign option_index = "" %}
{% assign option_values = "" %}

{% for option in product.options %}
{% if option == option_title %}
{% assign option_index = forloop.index %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% assign variant_option_value = "" %}
{% if option_index == 1 %}
{% assign variant_option_value = variant.option1 | handleize %}
{% elsif option_index == 2 %}
{% assign variant_option_value = variant.option2 | handleize %}
{% elsif option_index == 3 %}
{% assign variant_option_value = variant.option3 | handleize %}
{% endif %}
{% assign option_values = option_values | append:"," | append:variant_option_value %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign option_values = option_values | remove_first:"," | split:"," | uniq %}

{% if option_values.size > 1 %}
 <a href="{{ url }}" class="more-colors" style="border: 1px solid black;">MORE COLORS</a>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```